# Inject / copy one json object into another json objects to extend them

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I do following with javascript/nodejs:

**Injecting json result A (only one json object)**

```
[{
    "user": "userA",
    "group": "groupA"
}]
```

**into json result B (multiple json objects with the same structure)**

```
[{
    "picture": "picA",
    "city": "cityA",
    "year": "2016"
},
{
    "picture": "picB",
    "city": "cityB",
    "year": "2017"
}]
```

**and creating following desire json object C after injection A into B**

```
[{
    "user": "userA",
    "group": "groupA",
    "picture": "picA",
    "city": "cityA",
    "year": "2016"
},
{
    "user": "userA",
    "group": "groupA",
    "picture": "picB",
    "city": "cityB",
    "year": "2017"
}]
```

I need to combine two json results. But object A should be copied into all B objects for extending them.

Comment: Do properties on object A overwrite properties on object B?

Comment: Properties/fields in A could have the same name as in B, but they shouldn't overwrite anything in B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you only have primitives, the following will merge the properties without overwriting if there are duplicate property names:

```
let toBeCopied = [{
    "user": "userA",
    "group": "groupA"
}];

let result = [{
    "picture": "picA",
    "city": "cityA",
    "year": "2016"
},
{
    "picture": "picB",
    "city": "cityB",
    "year": "2017"
}];

let merged = result.map(r => Object.assign({}, toBeCopied[0], r));
```

If you want to overwrite elements of the old array (instead of creating a new array), do this instead:

```
for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    result[i] = Object.assign({}, toBeCopied[0], result[i]);
}
```

But if in the future any of the properties are objects, keep in mind only the object references will be copied (it won't deep clone).